# Our chat is dead

Tags: discussion

I'm moving and have edited this question to Meta after posting it on ux.se:

We have an issue on ux stackexchange, that is the [Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/ux-chat) is practically dead

My initial attempt of posting this on ux.se was to attract users to the chat on the hopes that we bring any sort of life to it, - i honestly hope i'm wrong when i say  i am skeptical that this question will be having exposure here, nevertheless how can we bring chat to life?

Are we maybe able to increase the exposure on the chat room? Incentivize chat users somehow? provide a chat widget on the side of the main page? or any ideas you can think of?

This is how the chat room looks like as of today:

[image: Chat]

As you see the last message was posted almost a month ago. This is crucial, since the Chat Room is a great place for:

1. Discussions
2. Community Engagement
3. A chance for questions that don't have a place on the main page

When new users arrive to ux.se often they post questions that are completely out of the community standards or the [guidelines](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and one comment that we often respond with, "maybe this question is more suitable for chat".

As a new user: why would i in my right mind post my question on the chat when i see that the last message was 26 days ago **which btw was indeed a question <s>that never got answered?</s>**

I'm certain that our modest community size plays a role in how active the chat is, but i'm certain if we try to join and bring life to the chat room we might reflect some positive enhancements on the platform including the quality of questions asked.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your contribution to UXSE Meta. We would like to encourage members of the community to help improve UXSE, and the chat room is something that could do with some rethink :)

Comment: The chat is currently very hard to find. When I looked for it under "chat" in the "hamburger menu", I only found [Identity and abuse in software build around anonymity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105980/identity-and-abuse-in-software-build-around-anonymity). I couldn't even find the main chatroom when browsing through frozen chatrooms (I probably overlooked it in the long list); it's only through the link in this post that I found it.

Answer (score 1):

Chat isn’t supported in the iOS app. I’ve used Stack Exchange for years and never knew there was a chat room until clicking the link in this question. When I clicked the link I was taken to the mobile website. I don’t see a way to discover chat in the mobile app.

What if we relaxed rules on the questions allowed in the Q&A section? I have always understood the comments section on questions/answers to be the chat room supporting those questions & answers.

Comment: I agree 150%! it sometimes feels our current rules allow a very specific criteria of questions, which i think is kind of ironic when considering how the discipline is not as mature as other disciplines...

I've asked tons of hypothetical questions which were rejected in the past to an extent where it became demotivating to even ask anything; it's more convenient to workout the solutions on my own than put effort into a question to only get rejected. I wish we can work a bit on the tolerance degree

Comment: I believe that the required points for chatting has been lowered. I only recently saw that I could acces the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, that chat is fairly dead. A more appropriate for the chat now would be a message board. Regardless, it would be great if the chat is visited more often by other members of UX.SE

Perhaps having more events in the chat could work, I was thinking of posting a question serie like 'Struggle Sunday' where you have a question with 'would you rather have...' that can be fun to answer / discuss.

Answer (score 0):

There are talks with moderators from other communities about how we can make better use of the chat rooms. The AMA with UXPin that was hosted by GD.SE provided some valuable lessons on organizing events, and conversations about collaborating with other communities to host some events are underway.

Stay tuned for more...